# Set scale limits in rworldmap

Tags: r, rworldmap

I've mapped my country code data to a map using mapCountryData.

```
wvs_ag_map_data = joinCountryData2Map(wvs_ag, joinCode="NAME", nameJoinColumn="Country")

wvs_ag_map = mapCountryData(wvs_ag_map_data, nameColumnToPlot="Agree_w", 
                            mapTitle = "Proportion of population agreeing men should have more jobs", 
                            xlim = c(0, 1))
```

My issue is that the scale in the map generated is from 0.1594325 to 0.932434.

Is there a way to simply make this scale 0 to 1? I tried with the "xlim", but that didn't seem to accomplish anything.